# Calculating distance from a laser line using opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to the python language, and I've been trying to alter the code found at this excellent tutorial by Shaneormonde found here:

```
https://shaneormonde.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/webcam-laser-rangefinder/
```

I've copied his exact code I'm interested in below:

```
## program written by Shane Ormonde 7th sept 2013
## updated on 25th January 2014
## calculates the distance of a red dot in the field of view of the webcam.

import cv2
from numpy import *
import math

#variables
loop = 1
dot_dist = 0

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()

 else:
    rval = False
    #print "failed to open webcam"

 if rval == 1 :

    while loop == 1:
            cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
            rval, frame = vc.read()
            key = cv2.waitKey(20)
            if key == 27: # exit on ESC
                loop = 0
             num = (frame[...,...,2] > 236)
             xy_val =  num.nonzero()

             y_val = median(xy_val[0])
             x_val = median(xy_val[1])

             #dist = ((x_val - 320)**2 + (y_val - 240)**2 )**0.5 #    distance of dot from center pixel
             dist = abs(x_val - 320) # distance of dot from center    x_axis only

             print " dist from center pixel is " + str(dist)

             # work out distance using D = h/tan(theta)

             theta =0.0011450*dist + 0.0154
             tan_theta = math.tan(theta)

             if tan_theta > 0: # bit of error checking
                  obj_dist =  int(5.33 / tan_theta)

              print "\033[12;0H" + "the dot is " + str(obj_dist) + "cm  away"
  elif rval == 0:
          print " webcam error "
```

I've been able to get this code to work using a webcam and a laser pointer as outlined on his website. But I would like to alter his code in order to use a laser line, as opposed to just a dot. So I would be calculating the distance over an entire laser line, as opposed to just a point. Something very similar to this example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXeia4NFbx8
```

But as I am very new to python, I am at a loss as to how to adapt the above code to calculate distance over a laser line, as opposed to just one point.

Any help on adapting the above code (or supplying your own code if you some) would be greatly appreciated.